# Memory leak from pyarrow?

Tags: python, pandas, parquet, pyarrow

For the parsing of a larger file, I need to write in a loop to a large number of parquet files successively. However, it appears that the memory consumed by this task increases over each iteration, whereas I would expect it to remain constant (as nothing should be appended in memory). This makes it tricky to scale.

I've added a minimum reproducible example which creates 10 000 parquet and loop appends to it.

```
import resource
import random
import string
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import pandas as pd


def id_generator(size=6, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))

schema = pa.schema([
                        pa.field('test', pa.string()),
                    ])

resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_NOFILE, (1000000, 1000000))
number_files = 10000
number_rows_increment = 1000
number_iterations = 100

writers = [pq.ParquetWriter('test_'+id_generator()+'.parquet', schema) for i in range(number_files)]

for i in range(number_iterations):
    for writer in writers:
        table_to_write = pa.Table.from_pandas(
                            pd.DataFrame({'test': [id_generator() for i in range(number_rows_increment)]}),
                            preserve_index=False,
                            schema = schema,
                            nthreads = 1)
        table_to_write = table_to_write.replace_schema_metadata(None)
        writer.write_table(table_to_write)
    print(i)

for writer in writers:
    writer.close()
```

Would anyone have any idea what causes this leak and how to prevent it?

Comment: Can you state your pandas version?

Comment: Pandas: 0.22.0
PyArrow: 0.10.0

Comment: Please update to `pandas>=0.23`. There is a leak in Pandas which also affects `pyarrow`.

Comment: I tried and have the same memory leakage.

Comment: Update to ```pyarrow==0.15.0``` helped me.

Answer (score 4):

We aren't sure what is wrong, but some other users have reported as yet undiagnosed memory leaks. I added your example to one of the tracking JIRA issues https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-3324

Answer (score 3):

**Update on 2022:**

I've spent several days on memory leak issue from pyarrow. Please see [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-11007) for a better understanding. I'll paste the key points below. Basically, they are saying it is **not a library memory leak issue**, rather it is a **common behavior.**

*Pyarrow uses jemalloc, a custom memory allocator which does its best to hold onto memory allocated from the OS (since this can be an expensive operation).*  Unfortunately, this makes it difficult to track line by line memory usage with tools like `memory_profiler`.  There are a couple of options:

1. You could use [this library function](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.total_allocated_bytes.html#), `pyarrow.total_allocated_bytes` to track allocation instead of using `memory_profiler`.
2. You can also put the following line at the top of your script, this will configure jemalloc to release memory immediately instead of holding on to it (this will likely have some performance implications). However, I used it, but did not work.

```py
import pyarrow as pa
pa.jemalloc_set_decay_ms(0)
```

The behavior you are seeing is pretty typical for jemalloc.  For further reading, you can also see these other issues for more discussions and examples of jemalloc behaviors:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-6910

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-7305

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @user3503711 we had aggressive memory allocation issues with PyArrow. PyArrow was on macOS, using its `mimalloc` backend instead of `jemalloc`. PyArrow allocated memory for itself in ranges of gigabytes, killing our parallel pytest test runner (each worker allocated massively memory, causing Github Actions to silently fail). Note this was on a lot of *read* and little write.

We could not completely get rid of PyArrow memory issues and suspect an internal leak there. However we managed to mitigate issues somewhat and lower the memory consumption so that the test run completes.

- Try set parameters to `pyarrow.parquet.read_table`. Some parameters you might want to play around are `read_table(f, use_threads=False pre_buffer=False, memory_map=True)`.
- If you are using `pytest` testing library, make sure you do not use Arrow/DataFrame in test fixtures, as [pytest may cache these objects behind the scenes](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/5642#issuecomment-1279612764)
- Delete your objects explicitly using Python's `del` keyword
- Try to force `pyarrow` to garbage collect

```py
    import gc
    gc.collect()
    import pyarrow
    pool = pyarrow.default_memory_pool()
    pool.release_unused()

    p = psutil.Process()
    rss = p.memory_info().rss

    print(f"Pool bytes {pool.bytes_allocated():,} max memory {pool.max_memory():,}, RSS after cleaning is {rss:,}")
```

Furthermore

- If it is possible switch to [FastParquet library](https://github.com/dask/fastparquet) instead of PyArrow. There might be compatibility issues preventing you to do so.